# vanilla js with rxjs : autocomplete search

Tags: javascript, rxjs, autocomplete, observable

I'm trying to use rxjs with vanillajs to implement an autocomplete functionality.

I created an **index.html** page containing input text and **index.js** to handle **"keyup"** event and send request to the server .As it is just a demonstration, I used a json-server library to mock the API .

What I want is as the user put characters, the server send API request only if the character is not the same as the previous request

**For example, if he puts: "Ev" a request is sent, then he deletes "v"
then puts again that "v" the server doesn't send a request to the
server again, since it has been sent for "Ev" .**

To do that I used **distinctUntilChanged()** like the code below but it does not work (The API works fine).

```
import { debounceTime, map, distinctUntilChanged } from "rxjs/operators";
import { fromEvent } from "rxjs";
const url = "http://localhost:3000/clubs?q=";
let inputTxt = document.getElementById("text-input");
let textChange$ = fromEvent(inputTxt, "keyup");
let autoSuggest$ = textChange$.pipe(
  debounceTime(1000),
  distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.target.value == curr.target.value),

  map((e) => fetch(url + e.target.value).then((response) => response.json()))
);
```

And this is the HTML

```
<body>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Search"
      id="text-input"
    />

    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not comparing the `target` element in the previous state, just the previous event object. `target` is still a reference to the same element, so the value is always the same:

```js
distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.target.value == curr.target.value),
```

Instead, you can use `map` to store the value before comparison:

```js
let inputTxt = document.getElementById("text-input");
let textChange$ = fromEvent(inputTxt, "keyup");

let autoSuggest$ = textChange$
  .pipe(
    map(e => e.target.value), // Extract value here
    debounceTime(1000),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    mergeMap(value => fetch(url + value).then((response) => response.json()))
  )
```